# Binding portion of a SSRS ServerReport ReportPath to app setting in web.config

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

In an aspx page I have a ReportViewer set up like this:

```
 <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="rvReport" runat="server" ShowPromptAreaButton="false" ProcessingMode="Remote" AsyncRendering="false" SizeToReportContent="true" ShowToolBar="true" CssClass="reportViewer">
    <ServerReport ReportPath="/<ReplaceMe>/Reports/report1" />
</rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

What I'd like to do is be able to specify the value of <ReplaceMe> with a value from the app settings section of my web.config.

Something like

```
<appsettings>
    <add key="ReportPathFolder" value="FOLDER1"/>
</appsettings>
```

I've tried this:

```
<ServerReport ReportPath="/<%$ AppSettings:ReportPathFolder %>/Reports/report1" />
```

But it doesn't work.  I get a path is invalid error.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this from your code behind page, as described here:  [how to open ssrs report from asp web page using report viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12607920/how-to-open-ssrs-report-from-asp-web-page-using-report-viewer)

So you would pull "ReplaceMe" out of your AppSettings, and your code would look something like this:

```
ServerReport serverReport = reportViewer.ServerReport;
serverReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("http://<Server Name>/reportserver");
serverReport.ReportPath = ="/<ReplaceMe>/Reports/report1";
```

Comment: That's what I've got in place right now on one test page. And it works great.  I'm looking for a solution using the .aspx page directly since I can right a simple find->replace and point it to the 50 or so pages that have reports.

Comment: Okay, I'm not sure how to do it that way, either.